# Bean Validation Groups - Understanding it correctly

Tags: java, javabeans, bean-validation

I am trying to understand the Groups in Bean validation.

So for instance if I have a bean and I want only certain field validated for certain cases, I should group them?

```
 @NotNull (groups=MyClassX.class)
 @Min (groups=MyClassA.class)  // 1
 @Pattern(xxxxx, groups = MyClassA.class) // 2
 private String field1;

 @NotNull (groups=MyClassX.class)
 @Min (groups=MyClassX.class)
 @Pattern(xxxxx, groups=MyClassX.class))
 private String field2;

 @NotNull (groups=MyClassX.class)
 @Min (groups=MyClassX.class)
 @Pattern(xxxxx, groups=MyClassA.class) //3
 private String field3;
```

My understanding from the above example is, if I pass `MyClassA` to validator, then only `@Min` and `@Pattern` for `Field1` and `@Pattern` for `field3` are only validated? (marked with numbers 1,2 and 3)

Did I understand this correctly?
I haven't left any fields without `Groups` attribute. So no default group.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, here is the [javax.validation javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html)

When you want to validate a bean, you actually call [Validator.validate(T object,         java.lang.Class... groups)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#validate%28T,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

It will then check the validations constraints of the specified groups. It allows to use several validation cases.

**What you describe in your question is accurate.**

Note, if you do not put any group on your constraints, then the constraints belong to the default group, which is the only validated group if you don't specify any group when calling validate(T object).